# How to output to console (but not stderr) on .NET even if the entire command output is redirected to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to be able to force some output on the console, even if the app is invoked with the output redirection.
I specifically do not want to use stderr.

How can this be done in .NET?

**EDIT 1**

I tried `Console.Out` and `Console.OpenStandardOutput` - both are redirected.

**EDIT 2**

- `Console.WriteLine` - uses `Console.Out`
- `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())) ; sw.WriteLine();`

Both options respect redirection.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: See EDIT 1 ....

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried with `Console.Out` and `Console.OpenStandardOutput`? Can you show us as much code as possible to get towards a [mcve]?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the invocation of a process has specifically redirected the output, it's for a reason, including possibly that they very much _don't want any output on the console_. I'm sure there's some way to mess around with the underlying console subsystem (see the many p/invoke-based solutions on this site for examples) to temporarily disconnect any active redirection while you write to the console and then restore when you're done, but surely this is a horrible idea by any standard.

Comment: AFAIK there are only 2 output streams: StdOut (usable with e.g. `Console.WriteLine`) and StdErr (usable with e.g. `Console.Error.WriteLine`). It's just how Windows command line apps work, and how they have always worked.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - thanks for the reasoning. But I still want to know if this is possible.

Comment: It's software. I guarantee it's _possible_. The completely useless answer to the question you've asked is "yes". The question is, how much effort is required (I'd hazard to say that it's **significant**), and whether it's even the right solution to whatever perceived problem you're trying to solve. "Is it possible?" questions are way too open-ended for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - you are right. I have changed the question into "How this can be done in .NET?". Thank you.

Comment: All due respect, I don't think that adding "in .NET" changes the fundamental essence of the question. There's no built-in support for anything like this in .NET, so you're going to wind up using .NET's native-interop features to access the console subsystem, which means your real question is still really just "Is it possible?" _generally_.

Comment: [Pinvoke required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter)

Comment: I thought Windows had 9 output streams.. but so well anyway, perhaps you need to adjust your perspective on it, install a logging library and log to (wherever it does now) plus (wherever you want it to, outside of the console)

Comment: @mark You should be able to use the [CONOUT$](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) (pseudo)file to refer to the console screen buffer, which is not affected by the standard streams redirection.